# Animate cursor following already animated element

Tags: javascript, css, animation

I have an element which has an animation for scaling up and down (like breathing effect) and I want to add cursor following.

My code works only If I delete the animation in CSS.

What I'm doing wrong?

looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.

```js
class FollowCursor {
  constructor(element, window) {
    this.element = element;
    this.w = window;
    this.w.onmousemove = this.move.bind(this);
  }

  move(e) {
    this.element.setAttribute(
      "style",
      `transform: translate(${e.clientX}px, ${e.clientY}px);`
    );
  }
}

const el = document.querySelector(".el")

const cursorFollowing = new FollowCursor(el, window)
```

````css
 .el {
   position: absolute;
   animation: a-breathing 8s infinite forwards;
   left: 0;
   top: 0;
   width: 30px;
   height: 30px;
   background-color: yellow;
 }

 div {
   position: relative
 }

 @keyframes a-breathing {
   0% {
     transform: scale(1);
   }

   60% {
     transform: scale(1.8);
   }

   100% {
     transform: scale(1);
   }
 }

```
````

```html
<div>
<div class="el">
</div>
</div>
```

[jsfiddle snippet](https://jsfiddle.net/januszeq/nk9c4rqs/)

Comment: @MohamadShiralizadeh wow. No...please. Don't give this kind of advice.

Comment: Maybe you can paste the css to help us to solve this issue.

Comment: I pasted css in the code.

Comment: @MohamadShiralizadeh why would you say that? Completely irrelevant to the question and based on opinion

Comment: @januszeq your JS and your CSS are both using the transform property, therefore the position is being overriden. You could try use top/left position instead: https://jsfiddle.net/brj8gzos/1/

Comment: @BrettGregson Sorry for miss understanding.

Comment: @MihaiT Sorry for miss understanding.

Comment: @januszeq make use of code snippet or [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) to show your code.

Comment: @isimi https://jsfiddle.net/januszeq/nk9c4rqs/

Answer (score 0):

I believe you'll get your expected behavior if you change this line

`transform: translate(${e.clientX}px, ${e.clientY}px);`

for this:

`position: absolute; top: ${e.clientY}px; left: ${e.clientX}px`

E.g.:  https://jsfiddle.net/cxszqdka/

Answer (score 0):

You're overwriting your transform attribute since you can only have one per element, so you need an element to move around and another div element to do the breathing; here is the solution:

```js
class FollowCursor {
  constructor(element, window) {
    this.element = element;
    this.w = window;
    this.w.onmousemove = this.move.bind(this);
  }

  move(e) {
    this.element.setAttribute(
      "style",
      `transform: translate(${e.clientX}px, ${e.clientY}px);`
    );
  }
}

const el = document.querySelector(".el")

const cursorFollowing = new FollowCursor(el, window)
```

```css
.el {
   position: absolute;
   left: 0;
   top: 0;
   width: 30px;
   height: 30px;
   background-color: yellow;
 }
.breathing-element {
  animation: a-breathing 8s infinite forwards;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: red;
}
 div {
   position: relative
 }

 @keyframes a-breathing {
   0% {
     transform: scale(1);
   }

   60% {
     transform: scale(1.8);
   }

   100% {
     transform: scale(1);
   }
 }
```

```html
<div>
<div class="el">
  <div class="breathing-element"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

You can also combine multiple values for the transform attribute following this pattern:

```
transform: translate | transform | scale | rotate
```